# Problem with Steam and Unity

Tags: unity, graphics, steam

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 and the whole reason that I did so was to be able to run Steam.

Well, Steam opens up just fine. But, once I actually start trying to play games, it's completely screwed. Crusader Kings 2, specifically. It won't open the game.

- Why is everything at the top of the screen?
- Why is it so hard to find everything now?
- Why does this alleged upgrade suck so badly when compared to what was upgraded *from*?
- And, most importantly, how do I go back to what worked?

I don't even care about Steam anymore. I want to completely uninstall it as well at this point.

Please assume that I know absolutely nothing about computers, even though I do.

Comment: Can you please give some hints in which way things do not work? Steam as well as what the unity problem is. In which was Steam and Crusader Kings is screwed?

Comment: @Danny I've edited your question. Remember that **this is not a blog**, just a site with *questions* and *answers*. If you want to, use [the chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/), there you can talk of any issue and free for any that you want to. But not here. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## Unity

It's totally normal that the menu is on the top. Mac OS X has this a long time ago and many people like it, which was the reason to do it like on a Mac I guess. If you do not like Unity you can install Gnome3 and some other Desktops via the Ubuntu Software Center. You can change between them in the login screen after installation.

To find things use the Dash. It's the Icon at the top in the Launcher (on the left side). You can also open it using the Super-Key.

## Steam

I guess (most likely the problem) that you are not using the proprietary drivers, which are needed for most 3D games. You can easily install them:

- Open the following application (via the Unity Dash if you're using Unity): "Software & Updates"
- In this application click the last tab (should be called "additional drivers")
- There choose the proprietary driver for your graphics card.
- Apply your choice.
- restart your computer

It will automatically download and install the driver you selected. After your restart, Steam games should work.

Comment: Steam works fine until I try to play a game. That's not the issue. Also, I don't know what the following terms that you used mean:  Mac OS X, Gnome 3, and Super-Key.  I have already downloaded the most updated proprietary drivers that I am able to.

Comment: Those terms are not that important. The Super-Key is the key on your keyboard which is in most cases a key with a Windows-Logo. Please describe in which way the game does not work. Does just nothing happen? Do you hear sound? Is your graphics card strong enough for the game? Please add a detailed error description in your question at the top. Also please try the way I described to install a new driver. It will also tell you which driver is used (in case it did not work).